# Google Sheets bug? query completed with an empty output

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

[image: image attached]

I have a named range in Google Sheets and I am making a simple query which should return a value but it doesn't work:

```
=QUERY(range2,"SELECT B WHERE A contains 'test' ")
```

It should return "2" but it sais that the query completed with an empty output.
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

actually, `QUERY` is known to behave like this and its caused by a superiority of numeric values over text string values in a given dataset. fix would be to select columns **A** and **B** and format them as **Plain text**

[image]

another approach would be to convert dataset within formula like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A:B),
 "SELECT Col2 
  WHERE Col1 contains 'test'"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I had the same problem in a column where I have dates and text, depending on the row... I fixed a "Plein text" to all to column and it solved the problem ! Thank you